# Sharepoint How To Uncheck Other in MultiChoice

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I'm using SharePoint Office 365 Online.

I have a list with multiple choice including an option to write in your own answer.  However, every field I create with multiple choice defaults to a auto check on the optional add on.  I would rather there not be any checkmarks.  How can I remove it?

See screenshots of settings.  Also using InfoPath 2013 for design help.

[image]

Copy of list settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the check mark to go to a different option for example "Pick and Pack" under the **Default value** make sure choice is highlight and type in "Pick and Pack"

If you do not want any value to be seen in the **Default value** click calculated Value and leave empty.

Hope that helps!